# Sqlx only accept string literal in query macro, how to use variable?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

The codes:

// very complex where clause combined from several runtime variables.

```
let query: String = String.from("where ..........");
let rows_num: i64 = sqlx::query!( &*query).fetch_one(connection)
```

The error from compiler:

```
error: expected string literal
--> src/abc.rs:80:25
|
80 | let rows_num: i64 = sqlx::query!(
| ____________^
81 | | &*query,
82 | | ).fetch_one(connection)
| |^
|
= note: this error originates in the macro sqlx::query (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

And the doc states:

> The query must be a string literal or else it cannot be introspected (and thus cannot be dynamic or the result of another macro).

I know the sqlx computes at compile time, my where clause computation is at run time.
I really want to use variable, because the where clause depends other several conditions.
Are there any ways to use variable in sqlx?

Comment: https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.5.7/sqlx/macro.query.html#query-arguments

Answer (score 6):

Using `sqlx::query()` function instead of the `sqlx::query!()` macro. The document doesn't mention it in their page.

Comment: The [readme on crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/sqlx) makes pretty extensive use of it before advertising its compile-time verification.